# way to sort by CPU% on 'top' by default?

Tags: macos, freebsd

When i run `top` on my Macbook (BSD?) i almost always want to sort by CPU%

it dosent seem to be the default, so I wind up typing 'o' (to sort) and type in 'cpu' and hit enter
all the time!

is there a way to make sort-by-CPU% the default or something?

Comment: Might be worth checking to make sure there isn't an alias already set for top with a different sort option

Comment: alias top="top -u" # Put this in your .bash_aliases file. Later command line options override earlier ones specifically so you can set defaults with a command like this.

Answer (score 6):

%CPU is the default sort column on every system I've ever used. But if it's not, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> to sort by %CPU. Note that it's not listed in interactive help, only the man page.

```
M         %MEM
N         PID
P         %CPU
T         TIME+
```

Comment: i am dumb and posted this in stackoverflow linux when using a Mac :D

Answer (score 5):

`top -o +%CPU`

As John Kugelman said, usually %CPU is a default sort column. Anyway, reading man top(1) seems a good idea.

Comment: This works for [http://boot2docker.io](Boot2Docker) distros

Comment: On OS X it's `top -o cpu`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the top manpage, you can use option `-o %CPU`, although that should already be the default. You could create an alias in your .bashrc (`alias top='top -o %CPU'`) to make this permanent.

```
-o  :Override-sort-field as:  -o fieldname
            Specifies  the  name of the field on which tasks will be sorted, independent of what is reflected in the configuration file.  You can prepend a '+' or '-' to the field name to
            also override the sort direction.  A leading '+' will force sorting high to low, whereas a '-' will ensure a low to high ordering.

            This option exists primarily to support automated/scripted batch mode operation.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to establish the sorting you prefer in `top` and then press `W` to save the configuration. Next time you start `top` it is going to load the config.

Press `h` in `top` to see keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: ooo never knew that, that's awesome thanks!

Comment: This does not work on my Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4.